# Error of binding class missing while building gradle project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.

> Cannot access output property 'sourceOutFolder' of task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'. Accessing unreadable inputs or outputs is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState(). See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/incremental_build.html#disable-state-tracking for more details.

   > java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\hpfq5\OneDrive\Desktop\PhotoEditor\SourceCode\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\gamebuzz\photoeditor\databinding\ActivityFinalBinding.java: not a regular file
```

I was building my Android project as usual but suddenly this happened. Everything was working well before this. I have build this project multiple times but never recieved such an error. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you share FinalActivity and its XML?

Comment: Actually the problem is now solved. There was issue in gradle build. Then I cleaned and rebuilt the project using ./gradlew clean and ./gradlew build